# Which formula of confidence interval should I choose?

Tags: confidence-interval

I am making a survey and I want to post the results with 95% confidence interval. The problem is I found multiple formulas to compute it and I don't know which one I have to choose.

The 2 formulas are :

- $I_c = \left[\bar x - t_{\alpha}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\ ;\ \bar x + t_{\alpha}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$
- $I_c = \left[\bar x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ ;\ \bar x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$

**What are the differences between those formulas and in which case should I choose which formulas?**

Comment: Are you sure the third formula doesn't actually have terms of the form "$\pm t_{\alpha/2}\,\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$"?

Comment: @whuber No, I got this information from this french website: http://www.bibmath.net/dico/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=./i/intconfiance.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  It is incorrect: that is a typographical error, as I suspected.

Comment: Okay ... but what is $t_{\alpha/2}$ and why use it?

Comment: Your source explains what it is.  As to the "why," see posts about [one-tailed vs. two-tailed tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tailed).

Comment: @whuber I asked the author of my source and you're right, there is an error in the formula but it wasn't what you said. We don't have to use $t_\alpha/2$ to compute the confidence interval.

Comment: Please do not confuse $t_\alpha/2$ with $t_{\alpha/2}$: they are quite different things.  The latter is an essential part of formulas for two-sided confidence intervals.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant $t_{\alpha/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula use the exact standard error to compute the confidence interval. The second one is just a rule of thumb to approximate the first one.

Indeed, the mean of the sample $\bar x$ is an estimation of the mean of the population $\mu$. Because $\bar x$ is an estimation, we need to compute the standard error of the mean $\sigma_{\bar x}$ to know the deviation of this estimation. The formula of the SEM is: $\sigma_{\bar x} = \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ with $s$ the standard deviation of the sample and $n$ the size of the sample.

Now, we want to calculate the 95% confidence margin of error for $\bar x$. The critical value for this level of confidence is $t_\alpha = 1.96$. So, the margin of error is: $MOE = t_\alpha \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$. **It is the first formula!**

To facilitate the calculation of the margin of error, we can use a rule of thumb. Indeed, the standard deviation of the sample $s$ from a Bernoulli distribution is $s = p(1-p)$ with $p$ the probability (in the case of a survey, it is the frequency of votes for a candidate). As $p(1-p) \leq 0.5$ and $t_\alpha \approx 2$, we can rewrite the first formula: $MOE = 2 \frac{0.5}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. **Here is the second formula.**

There are some limitations when we want to use the rule of thumb. Indeed, the standard deviation $s$ can be smaller than 0.5 when the proportion $p$ is closer to 0 or 1. That's why it's recomanded to check the following conditions before use the second formula:

- $n \geq 30$
- $np \geq 5$
- $n(1-p) \geq 5$

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you will want the first one.  I believe the second is for data that has already been normalized, and I'm not sure what the third one is for.

I hope someone has a better answer to this.

Comment: I remove the third formula, it was an error. About the second one, how can I use it to compute a 99% confidence interval because $t_\alpha$ is not present?

Comment: How is t_alpha not present?

Comment: I mean, I want to use this formula $I_c = \left[\bar x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ ;\ \bar x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$ to compute a 99% confidence interval. But how can I do it because $t_\alpha$ is not present? With the first formula, I just have to replace $t_\alpha$ by $2.58$ to do it.

Comment: I am sorry but I'm still quite confused about you're answer. You say the second formula is used for normalized data. I try both formulas on normalized data and I got different results. Why?

Comment: I found why the second formula give me another result. It's because it's a rule of thumb to approximate the real value. It's not used just when the data are normalized but when the sample follow a Bernoulli distribution. I explain that in my answer.